# Cannot Insert data into SQL Server database using a asp.net web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I have never made a web application using asp.net with C# to insert data into a database in SQL Server 2012.

When I run my application and after entering all the information I am required to enter into the fields, I click on my submit button triggering the `OnClick` event, which executes the code below.

However when I go to check my database, I am seeing that the data I insert is not making it into the tables, and I am not getting any error messages.

In the code for my .aspx.cs file, I have the following code to insert data into my database's 'Buyer' and 'CustAddress' tables:

```
SqlParameter FirstName = new SqlParameter( "@FirstName", tb_firstName.Text );
SqlParameter LastName = new SqlParameter( "@LastName", tb_lastName.Text );

insertBuyer.Parameters.Add( FirstName );
insertBuyer.Parameters.Add( LastName );
insertBuyer.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Buyer VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName)";

SqlParameter street = new SqlParameter("@street", tb_streetAddress.Text);
SqlParameter city = new SqlParameter("@city", tb_city.Text);
SqlParameter state = new SqlParameter("@state", tb_state.Text);
SqlParameter zip = new SqlParameter("@zip", tb_zip.Text);

insertCustAddress.Parameters.Add(street);
insertCustAddress.Parameters.Add(city);
insertCustAddress.Parameters.Add(state);
insertCustAddress.Parameters.Add(zip);
insertCustAddress.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CustAddress VALUES(@street, @city, @state, @zip)";
```

I'm not exactly sure why my data is not making it into my database's tables.

Please don't tear me apart to badly, this is all new to me, and any help will be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: have you used any `ExecuteNonQuery` or `executeQuery` in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you have already opened the db connection

Just change your code like this

```
insertBuyer.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Buyer VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName)";
//insertBuyer.Connection=your connection

insertBuyer.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@FirstName", tb_firstName.Text );
insertBuyer.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@LastName", tb_lastName.Text );
insertBuyer.ExecuteNonQuery();// inserts your buyer info

insertCustAddress.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CustAddress VALUES(@street, @city, @state, @zip)";
//insertCustAddress.Connection=your connection
insertCustAddress.Parameters.AddWithValue("@street", tb_streetAddress.Text);
insertCustAddress.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", tb_city.Text);
insertCustAddress.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", tb_state.Text);
insertCustAddress.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip", tb_zip.Text);
insertCustAddress.ExecuteNonQuery();// inserts your customer info
```